# MVC Unity Reset DI when user logs out

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using unity as my IoC and when the application loads up I setup my initial DI in the global.asax that my login screen needs.

When the user logs in I then setup my main DI that creates all the DI stuff for the rest of the application. One of the objects I am creating is storing the user details from the login screen and I am using that dto to inject into my services to be used for authorisation.

The issue I have is when the user logs out. I need to dispose of the dto that contains the user details.

Is there anyway to dispose an object within unity that is not being called within the global.asax?

**EDIT**

In my bootstrapper class that is being called from the global.asax. I only need to setup the DI for the security at this point.

```
Dim container As IUnityContainer = Bootstrapper.UnityContainer

        SecurityContainer.RegisterContainer(container)
        MiscContainer.RegisterMiscContainer(container)

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(New UnityDependencyResolver(container))

        ' Setup controller factory.
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(New UnityControllerFactory(container))
```

In my RegisterContainer classes they just have simple registrations like below.

```
container.RegisterType(Of ILeadService, LeadService)(New ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```

In my login post method in the controller I have the following code. This will go off to the security service to authenticate the user. If they are authenticated then I need to setup the next part of the DI which is the rest of the application. The reason I have to setup this DI here instead of the global.asax is because I need to use the securityDto in all my other services.

```
Public Function LogOnWindow(loginViewModel As LoginViewModel) As ActionResult

        Dim action As ActionResult = Nothing

        ' Authorise the user.
        Dim securityResponse As ISecurityResponse = Me._securityService.AuthenticateUser(loginViewModel.UserName,
                                                                                         loginViewModel.Password)

        ' Check the response is successful.
        If (securityResponse.IsSuccessful) Then

            ' Set the application id.
            securityResponse.SecurityDto.CurrentDealerApplicationId = Me._applicationType

            ' Setup the bootstrapper with the security credentials.
            Bootstrapper.InitialiseAfterLogin(securityResponse.SecurityDto)

            ' Redirect to the main application.
            action = Me.RedirectToAction("KiaDashGrid",
                                         "Kia",
                                         New With {.Language = "en-gb"})

        Else

            ' Create an error message.
            loginViewModel.MessageManager.Merge(securityResponse.MessageManager.GetMessageCollection())

        End If

        If (action Is Nothing) Then
            action = Me.View(loginViewModel)
        End If

        Return action

    End Function
```

The securityResponse.SecurityDto contains the user credentials that I inject into the rest of the applications services.

Example of a service constructor using the dto.

```
Public Class LeadService
    Inherits ServiceBase
    Implements ILeadService

    Public Sub New(mapper As IMapper,
                   uow As IUnitOfWork,
                   leadRepository As ILeadRepository,
                   securityDTO As ISecurityDTO)
        MyBase.New(securityDTO)
        Me._mapper = mapper
        Me._uow = uow
        Me._leadRepository = leadRepository
        Me._fetchStrategy = New FetchStrategy(Of Lead)()

    End Sub
End Class
```

It is this dto that I want to reset when the user logs out.

Below is the code in my logout action method.

```
<HttpGet()> _
    Public Function LogOut() As ActionResult

        ' Need to clear the security dto credentials here.            

        Return Me.RedirectToAction("LogOnWindow",
                                   "KiaLogin",
                                    New With {.Language = "en-gb"})
    End Function
```

I hope this info is more helpful.

**EDIT - 19/02/2014**

I have created my own PerSessionLifetimeManager class but when I log two users into the application the second users gui key is always used.

In my bootstrapper class I have tried the following ways but neither have worked so far.

```
Dim manager As New PerSessionLifetimeManager()
        manager.SetValue(securityDto)
        container.RegisterType(Of ISecurityDTO, SecurityDTO)(manager)

container.RegisterInstance(securityDto, New PerSessionLifetimeManager())
```

The PerSessionLifetimeManager class below.

```
Public Class PerSessionLifetimeManager
    Inherits LifetimeManager

    Private ReadOnly _key As Guid = Guid.NewGuid()

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function GetValue() As Object
        Return HttpContext.Current.Session(Me._key.ToString())
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub RemoveValue()
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(Me._key.ToString())
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub SetValue(newValue As Object)
        HttpContext.Current.Session(Me._key.ToString()) = newValue
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Sounds a little suspiciously. You set up something upon user login but what about other users? What is the lifetime of such long-living object? Where is it stored (session?)?

Comment: The user details is specific to each user, so they will have their own information.

Comment: I know that. I ask how you set it up with unity.

Comment: I have updated my original post to include more details.

Comment: What is `InitialiseAfterLogin`?

Comment: It is very similar to the first block of code. It registers the rest of my containers with unity.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. You register objects as singletons (`ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`) and that is why I asked about lifetime management. The problem is this won't work in multiuser environment, consecutive users will overwrite these settings upon logging. DI is not only about composing but also about lifetime management. I suggest you to rethink your approach.

Comment: Would the PerResolveLifetimeManager or the HttpContextLifetimeManager make any difference?

Comment: Nope. The first one works in the scope of a single resolve call. The second works in the scope of single http context. What you would need is this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178862/mvc3-unity-framework-and-per-session-lifetime-manager-issue You don't need to dispose the data as the server will terminate sessions on its own.

Answer (score 1):

After a long discussion it turns out that you are using wrong lifetime manager, the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`.

Instead, you need a manager that stored the data so that it survives multiple requests. The session container does that and so does the `SessionLifetimeMananager` like this one:

[MVC3, Unity Framework and Per Session Lifetime Manager Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178862/mvc3-unity-framework-and-per-session-lifetime-manager-issue)

You don't need to unregister anything as the session containers are maintained by the application server and terminated automatically.

Comment: I tried the PerSessionLifetimeManager class but it still remembers the second users credentials. I have updated my post with what I have tried so far.

Comment: Can you show the code of your `PerSessionLifetimeManager`?

Comment: I have updated my post with the code for the PerSessionLifetimeManager

Comment: I have had a look at the container and it seems to store the last PerSessionLifetimeManager that has been created for the last logged in user which is why it is pulling out the wrong data.

Comment: I've built a small application that uses this and I believe different users get different data as long as `RegisterInstance` is called properly in different contexts. Are you sure you don't test this in different tabs? Browsers share sessions between tabs. To test this, use two different browsers.

Comment: Is it possible if you are able to send me the application? I have been running my tests on two different browsers. At the moment I have tried a work around which uses session but its not the cleanest approach.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxM-2qYSdb5AOGFLUWtweXh0Y00/edit?usp=sharing will delete it soon

Comment: Note this is stripped down to an absolute minimum.