# Cannot get a working Unity Session Lifetime Manager, ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I've read and Googled everything on this, but can't seem to get it to work.  I created a custom `LifetimeManager` for Unity in my MVC5 application based on these posts:

- [MVC3 Unity Framework and Per Session Lifetime Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178862/mvc3-unity-framework-and-per-session-lifetime-manager-issue)
- [This may be the issue I am experiencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859241/mvc-unity-reset-di-when-user-logs-out?lq=1)

Here is my `SessionLifetimeManager`

```
public class SessionLifetimeManager : LifetimeManager
{
    private string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
    }

    public override void RemoveValue()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(key);
    }

    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = newValue;
    }
}
```

I only have a few types I'm playing with, here is the relevant registrations in *UnityConfig.cs*:

```
container.RegisterType<IEpiSession, EpiSession>(new SessionLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionConstructor(config.AppServerURI, config.PathToSysConfig));
container.RegisterType<IReportRepository, EpicorReportRepository>(new TransientLifetimeManager());

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Note that the `EpicorReportRepository` has a dependency on `IEpiSession` via constructor injection.

```
public class EpicorReportRepository : IReportRepository
{
    private IEpiSession session;

    // DI constructor
    public EpicorReportRepository(IEpiSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }
// ...
}
```

**My Problem:** After the first user / session connects to the application, every new user / session after that seems to still be using the `EpiSession` object and credentials that the first user had create/injected for him.  This seems to be a common pattern used on the interwebs, so I'm wondering what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

How did you test that `IEpiSession` is the same in different `Session`s?

**Try to open you application from different browsers. If you open several tabs in the same browser then the same session is used.**

I checked your code and it works for me.
There is the only one difference in `SetResolver()`:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
    type => container.Resolve(type),
    types => container.ResolveAll(types));
```

The full registration code is the following:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IEpiSession, EpiSession>(
            new SessionLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor("config.AppServerURI", "config.PathToSysConfig"));
        container.RegisterType<IReportRepository, EpicorReportRepository>(new TransientLifetimeManager());

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
            type => container.Resolve(type),
            types => container.ResolveAll(types));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ilya, I'm going to assume you are correct, don't have time to test this, but it confirms something I was suspecting - the real EpiSession object is 3rd party, and I think it is doing something under the hood where connection is pooled or shared even though there are two disparate EpiSession objects in memory (one per session). I definitely had two session, checked that with some debug code, but I had not yet tested to see if I had two separate EpiSession object - d'uh. I bet it will show I do, like I said - just need to figure out why it is using only one connection to ERP system.

Comment: @AdamNofsinger, Well, you can change lifetime for `EpiSession` to Transient and check how that instances will work. It might help you to verify your assumptions.